# Does anyone can give me any suggestion regarding which kind of software should I use for creating Video Animation?

Tags: animation

Does any one can give me any suggestion regarding which kind of software should I use for creating Video  Animation? I am a Web Designer but I don't have a good knowledge in Video Animation. At this point I just wanted to get some ideas before i try to use any software. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Movie Maker.Windows has discontinued support, but by doing a general search it can be found and it does run without error on Windows 10. Adobe Creative Cloud has tools for animation as well. Deviant Art is a resource for the artists that provide recommendations for open source animation tools. This site is dated, but has a long list of free open source tools https://www.nyfa.edu/student-resources/best-free-open-source-animation-software/ Also download trials if applicable to try software out.

Adobe Photoshop, illustrator and after effects all have animation features. Check Adobe as they do rename their products. The also have a YouTube channel with demos.

Comment: What the name of the software that are used in Adobe Creative Cloud for Video Animation
?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an easy software to create video animation you need to try viddyoze: bit.ly/3CfEWMH

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29794577)